# Why is my WPF KeyDown handler not catching CTRL+A?

Tags: wpf, keyboard, keydown

I have a `ListView` with the following `KeyDown` event handler:

```
private void ListViewOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.A)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("KeyDown is A");
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        {
            ListViewHelper.SelectAll((ListView)sender);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet the `Debug.WriteLine` is only ever invoked, i.e. I see `KeyDown is A`
 in my output window, if I only press key `A`. If I press `CTRL`, the event is invoked, but `e.Key` shows as `LeftCtrl` (using a breakpoint), and hold `CTRL` down and press `A`, the `Debug.WriteLine` is not invoked. Using a breakpoint for debugging shows that while I am holding `CTRL` down, the handler keeps getting invoked for `LeftCtrl` only.

Comment: Can someone please explain the down-vote? I have found numerous search results showing that this is how to detect such a key-press combination, yet it is not working as expected. I would also like to know how the question was voted down the instant it was posted? Is there some little minded bureaucrat that sits waiting for questions to potentially vote down?

Comment: Can someome also please explain how in the name of all that is right, a question tagged WPF et al. is asking exactly why code that I wrote that relates to all the tags, can rightly be voted to close as "off-topic"?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the special combination is already handled by `ListBox` control.

Using `PreviewKeyDown` instead seems to work.
Pay attention by setting `e.Handled = true;`

Comment: It's not a `ListBox` but a `ListView`, quite different controls, and that key combination does nothing when I try and use it to select all items in the `ListView`.

Comment: @ProfK Quite different controls? ListView is derived from ListBox, and PreviewKeyDown just works. You didn't even try it, right?

Comment: @ProfK I'm sorry for the mistake, it should work the same way with ListView too.

Comment: @Clemens For my WPF knowledge and the way I use them, they are quite different. `PreviewKeyDown` has nothing do do with your comment, as I was referring to `ListView` not responding to CTRL+A, not saying `PreviewKeyDown` doesn't work before trying it. My comment was made at end of day yesterday, and at the same time I made a note to try `PreviewKeyDown`. But thanks for the info that on how the controls are related.

Comment: @Liuk It is not a mistake to say that the key combination is already handled by the ListBox class, because it is the base class of ListView. Hence the key combination is implicitly also handled by a ListView.